# Is this model structure prone to infinite loop?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, codeigniter, infinite-loop

I am trying to debug an issue on my codeigniter app in which my server is returning a 500 error because it hangs forever when I try to load a page with several posts.

This error is intermittent. 7 out of 10 times, my pages load fast and CI's profiler show execution times < 0.6.

The model for this uses this structure, in which different FROM clauses will be inserted depending on the request that is being made (ie, my posts, favorites, other's posts). There are no SQL errors, no PHP error. Only significant delay in processing and some Apache errors like

```
[Sat May 19 21:27:21 2012] [warn] mod_fcgid: process 21174 graceful kill fail, sending SIGKILL
[Sat May 19 21:27:27 2012] [notice] mod_fcgid: process /var/www/vhosts/example.com/httpdocs/blog/index.php(21174) exit(communication error), get stop signal 9
```

Is this kind of SQL model prone to infinite loops or some other kind of problem that may justify my server going bonkers?

```
class Home_model extends CI_Model {

    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    function count_posts($author_id = NULL, $section = NULL, $user_id = NULL, $origin = NULL)
    {
        $clause = $this->clause($author_id, $section, $user_id, $origin);

        $query = $this->db->query("
        SELECT  *
        $clause
        ");

        return $query->num_rows;
    }

    function clause($author_id, $section, $user_id, $origin = NULL)
    {
        if ($section == 'favorites') {

            $clause  = "FROM post RIGHT JOIN favorites ON post_id_fk = post_id WHERE user_id_fk = $user_id";

        } elseif (($section == 'posts') AND ($origin == 'user')) {

            $clause = "FROM post WHERE post_author_id = $author_id";

        } else {

            if ($author_id == NULL) {

                $clause = "FROM post";

            } else {

                $clause = "FROM post WHERE post_author_id = $author_id";
            }
        }

        return $clause;
    }
}
```

Comment: Its definitely prone to sql injection

Comment: none of the attributes being passed are amenable to user input -- how about loop?

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing that in your view you do something like

```
for ($i=0; $i<$this->count_posts(); $i++){
         // show posts
  }
```

?

Can you please post your view code?

But given you are probably doing something like that - it would be reasonable to assume that the count_posts() function in your model is probably returning a wrong number, causing your loop to become infinite.

To debug it, do something like

```
//for ($i=0; $i<$this->count_posts(); $i++){
         // show posts
// }
echo $count_posts();
```

and see if the output is always what you expect...